# Reveal li-nth-child number with jquery on click

Tags: jquery, list, css-selectors, click

I need the code to reveal the number of the nth-child list after a click on a div.

In example:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <div id="mydiv1"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="mydiv2"></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

My jquery script must return me the number of nth-child i clicked. For example, if i click on mydiv2, the script must return me "2".

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: where is your click event? Over which element the event will be triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("ul li").click(function(){

  alert ($(this).index()+1);

  });
});
```

or when you want the div to be the clicked element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("ul li div").click(function(){

  alert ($(this).parent().index()+1);

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/refan/8pryo1t2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul").on("click", "div", function() {
    var index = $("div").index(this);
    alert("Index: " + index);
  });
});
```